# SDL delta time reset

Tags: c++, time, sdl

I use SDL, and I make use of SDL_GetTicks() to get the delta time, but here is the problem:

```
auto currentTime = SDL_GetTicks();
float deltaTime = 0.f, lastTime = 0.f;

deltaTime = (currentTime - lastTime) / 1000.f;
lastTime = currentTime;
```

deltaTime is in seconds, and the terminal shows that the value of deltaTime is correct in seconds. But, how do I reset it? The problem is that if I have a sprite, a mesh or even a camera moving within a scene the fact is the movement thereof will speed up overtime as deltaTime's value increases. I tried different ways of resetting deltaTime, but they won't produce the right results:

I tried:

```
if (deltaTime > 1.f)
    deltaTime = 0.f; // or deltaTime -= 1.f;

if (deltaTime > (currentTime - lastTime)
    deltaTime = 0.f;
```

Both statements weren't used in conjunction with each other; but it shows that the problem lies in the fact I need a way to reset or 'restart' the timer. I can't change the value in currentTime because SDL_GetTicks() shouldn't be manipulated so.

How do I reset delta time?

Comment: What is the scope of your `currentTime` and `lastTime` variables?

Comment: I have a function which handles inputs which requires the said variables; they're within the scope of that function. I was thinking of making a Time class to accommodate these values though.

Comment: You need `lastTime` to be sufficiently long-lived that you get the value from, well, last time you looked. it sounds as if you didn't, hence the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably benefit from reading up about game loops. The following article is very useful.

http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/

This is roughly how I handle the game loop in my SDL games

```
const double FRAME_TIME = 1 / 60  // delta time for 60 FPS

double lastTime = SDL_GetTicks();
double frameCounter = 0;
double unprocessedTime = 0;
int frames = 0;

SDL_Event e;

while (isRunning)
{
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&e))
    {
        // HANDLE EVENTS
    }

    bool render = false;

    double startTime = SDL_GetTicks();
    double passedTime = startTime - lastTime;
    lastTime = startTime;

    unprocessedTime += passedTime;
    frameCounter += passedTime;

    if (frameCounter >= 1.0)
    {
        printf("FPS: %i | %f ms\n", frames, 1000.0 / ((double)frames));

        frames = 0;
        frameCounter = 0;
    }

    while (unprocessedTime > FRAME_TIME)
    {
        Update((float)FRAME_TIME);

        render = true;
        unprocessedTime -= FRAME_TIME;
    }

    if (render)
    {
        Render();
        frames++;
    }
    else
    {
        SDL_Delay(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your respose; but I prefer not to use other people's code. Your solution is invaluable, however. :-)